# magento 2 - category attribute with checkbox input throws exception on admin save

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I created an InstallData class to add category attribute with checkbox input type.

`$eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'attribute_id', [
'type'     => 'int',
'label'    => 'Your Category Attribute Name',
'input'    => 'checkbox',
'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
'visible'  => true,
'default'  => '0',
'required' => false,
'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
'group'    => 'Display Settings',
]);`

The attribute displays a checkbox properly on the admin category edit page, but saving the category does not save checked value. If I change the input type to 'boolean', catch error - "Class boolean doesn't exist". How can I fix it to save checkbox value?

Comment: howmany checkbox you want?

Comment: You should be using 'input' => 'boolean' not int

Comment: one checkbox @abhishek

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to display `boolean` attribute
(Yes/No) inside category page.

```
$categorySetup->addAttribute(
'catalog_category',
'page_not_found',
array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'label' => 'Display on 404 Page',
    'input' => 'select',
    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
    'sort_order' => 3,
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
    'group' => 'General Information',
));
```

**Note:** please change your values according to your requirement.